# Me da error en el campo AUTOINCREMENT-AndroidStudio

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Quiero crear una base de datos para una agenda y necesito crear una campo de tipo `AUTOINCREMENT`.

El caso es que cuando creo la base de datos en `Android Studio` con `SQLite` me lo subraya y me da el siguiente error:

> '(', ')',  or comma expected, got 'AUTOINCREMENT'.

El código es el siguiente:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

public class BDSQLite extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private String sql = "create table eventos(" +
        "idEvento int AUTOINCREMENT," +
        "nombreEvento varchar(40)," +
        "ubicacion varchar(60)," +
        "fechadesde date," +
        "horadesde time," +
        "fechahasta date," +
        "horahasta time," +
        "descripcion varchar(60))";

public BDSQLite(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory 
factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(sql);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

}
}
```

Gracias por vuestro tiempo.

Comment: Es `AUTO_INCREMENT` con el guión bajo.

Comment: me sigue saliendo el mismo error

Comment: @HelloThere no es con guión bajo es como lo has escrito solo tienes que definir el campo también como PRIMARY KEY: "idEvento integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT"

Comment: Gracias, ya me funciona :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AUTOINCREMENT` solo puede usarse con `PRIMARY KEY`, y debe ser `INTEGER`

```
idEvento INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT
```

[Documentacion Oficial](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

Answer (score 0):

Según la documentación de sqlLite:

"Debido a que la palabra clave `AUTOINCREMENT` cambia el comportamiento del algoritmo de selección de ROWID, `UTOINCREMENT` no está permitido en las tablas `WITHOUT ROWID` o en ninguna columna de la tabla que no sea `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`. Cualquier intento de utilizar `AUTOINCREMENT`en una tabla `WITHOUT ROWID` o en una columna que no sea la columna `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` genera un error."

Tendrás que agregar:

```
  idEvento INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
```

Answer (score 0):

Revisa las caracteristicas de [AUTOINCREMENT](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html),

> - La palabra clave AUTOINCREMENT impone una sobrecarga de CPU, memoria, espacio en disco y sobrecarga de E / S de disco y debe
>     evitarse si no es estrictamente necesario.
> - Por lo general no es necesario. En SQLite, una columna con el tipo INTEGER PRIMARY KEY es un alias para ROWID (excepto en las tablas
>     WITHOUT ROWID) que siempre es un entero con signo de 64 bits.
> - En un INSERT, si la columna ROWID o INTEGER PRIMARY KEY no recibe un valor explícito, se llenará automáticamente con un número entero no
>     utilizado, generalmente uno más que el ROWID más grande actualmente en
>     uso. Esto es cierto independientemente de si se utiliza o no la
>     palabra clave AUTOINCREMENT.
> - Si la palabra clave AUTOINCREMENT aparece después de INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, eso cambia el algoritmo automático de asignación de ROWID para
>     evitar la reutilización de ROWID durante la vida útil de la base de
>     datos. En otras palabras, el propósito de AUTOINCREMENT es evitar la
>     reutilización de ROWID de las filas previamente eliminadas.

de hecho usualmente se muestra el mensaje de error:

> Uncaught Error: AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY
>   KEY

**Por lo tanto es necesario definir como `PRIMARY KEY` el campo que definirás como `AUTOINCREMENT`.**

```
idEvento integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
```

Este sería el query que crearía la tabla correctamente:

```
private String sql = "create table eventos(" +
        "idEvento integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
        "nombreEvento varchar(40)," +
        "ubicacion varchar(60)," +
        "fechadesde date," +
        "horadesde time," +
        "fechahasta date," +
        "horahasta time," +
        "descripcion varchar(60))";
```